# New at EmberJS and need some help/advice on my login code

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm working on an EmberJS frontend to my Spring backend API and the first thing I needed to tackle was the "login" screen. I've been reading tutorials across the web and whatever I can find on Ember, however, the problem seems that there are just too many different versions of the same tutorials and different ways of doing the same thing. It's been confusing me, but, after a lot of toiling away, I think I may have finally managed to get my login screen to work (partly).

It authenticates nicely using ajax and I can see in the dev console that everything is working well.

Before I proceed any further, I first wanted to have people's opinions about the ember code I have written thus far and if it is within "best practices" for an ember application. Also, if there are any better ways to go about solving the same problem.

Secondly, I have no idea how to switch to a different view on a successful login. I admit I'm still not familiar with the concepts of ember, but the tutorials online just keep confusing me.

I'd really appreciate any help here. I'm a fast learner and I think that I can take things from here depending on the answers.

Here's the code from my app.js file:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

//------------------------------------------------------------
// Hold the details of the logged-in user
//------------------------------------------------------------
App.LoggedInDetails = Ember.Object.create({
    Fullname: null,
    CompanyName: null,
    TokenID: null,

    setDetails: function(fullname, companyname, tokenid)
    {
        this.Fullname = fullname;
        this.CompanyName = companyname;
        this.TokenID = tokenid;
    },

    clearDetails: function()
    {
        this.Fullname = null;
        this.CompanyName = null;
        this.TokenID = null;
    }
});

//------------------------------------------------------------
App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'logged-out'
});

App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    isError: false,
    errorMessage: null,

    authenticate: function()
    {
        var email = this.get('email');
        var password = this.get('password');

        var url = 'https://api.example.com/security/authenticateUser.json';

        $.ajax({
           url: url,
           type: 'POST',
           dataType:'json',
           data: {email: email, passwd: password},
           crossDomain: true,
           context: this,
           success: this.authenticateCompleted
        });

        console.log('Url: ' + url);
    },

    authenticateCompleted: function(data)
    {
        // Login was a success!
        if(data.status === 'OK')
        {
            console.log('status: ' + data.status);
            console.log('fullName: ' + data.fullName);
            console.log('tokenId: ' + data.tokenId);
            console.log('companyName: ' + data.companyName);

            // Populate the LoggedInDetails object
            App.LoggedInDetails.setDetails(data.fullName, data.companyName, data.tokenId);

            this.set('isError', false);
        }
        else
        {
            App.LoggedInDetails.clearDetails();
            this.set('errorMessage', 'Invalid Email/Password Combination');
            this.set('isError', true);

            console.log(data.status);
            console.log(data.description);
        }
    }
});

//------------------------------------------------------------
App.Router = Ember.Router.extend({
    enableLogging: true,
    root: Ember.Route.extend({
        index: Ember.Route.extend({
            route: '/',
            connectOutlets: function(router) {
                router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet({
                    viewClass: App.ApplicationView,
                    controller: router.get('applicationController')
                });
            }
        })
    })
});

//------------------------------------------------------------
App.LoggedInView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'logged-in'
});

App.LoggedInController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    Fullname: App.LoggedInDetails.get("Fullname")
});

//------------------------------------------------------------

App.initialize();
```

My problem stems from switching from the "logged-out" default view to the "logged-in" view, which is the actual UI of my application.

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest approach: add an `isLoggedIn` property to `ApplicationController` and set it to true when the user authenticates. Make `ApplicationView` render a template that uses `{{#if isLoggedIn}} ... {{else}} ... {{/if}}` to switch between the logged in view and the non-logged in view.

Comment: Yes, I thought of this approach before, but I don't think that it would be best practice in a complex application. I'm not sure, but I think I have to use routing or statemachine or something like that. But it's a little over my head and wanted to see a real example of how to do this in order to wrap my head around it.